# Is There an EF 6 ObjectContext / EntityObject Code Generator for VB.Net Compatible with VS 2019?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, vsix

Subject says it all. This is I think what I'm looking for:

[EF 6.x EntityObject Generator for VB.NET](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EF6xEntityObjectGeneratorforVBNET)

but it will not install (apparently since it does not explicitly support VS 2019) - but perhaps there's a way to hack it into installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rename VSIX to zip
2. Unpack it, go to `T\Data\`
3. Copy `EntityObjectVB_EF6.zip` to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\`

more info about templates [User templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-locate-and-organize-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019)

> User templates
>
> If you add a compressed (.zip) file that includes a
>   `.vstemplate` file to the user template directory, the template appears
>   in the new project and new item dialog boxes. By default, user
>   templates are located in:
>
> `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates`
>
> `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates`
>
> For example, the following directory has user project templates for
>   C#:
>
> `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#`